# How to use a custom icon as FCM default notification icon in AndroidManifest - Maui

Tags: c#, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, .net-maui

Following de FCM documentation a have set a default notification icon in AndroidManifest but I want to use a custom icon to be the com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon.
I already have this icon in the OnMessageReceived method with Build Action = MauiIcon:

```
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Giki.Maui.Resource.Mipmap.appicon)
                                  .SetContentTitle(titleNotification)
                                  .SetContentText(messageBody)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                  .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Now I want to use this "appicon" in the AndroidManifest (replace the ic_dialog_alert):

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />
```

I tried: android:resource="@mipmap/appicon" but doesn't work.

How can I use a custom icon as the default_notification_icon in AndroidManifest? Is it possible in Maui? Or do I have to choose one of the android:drawable/ options given?

Thanks!

Comment: You may consider creating a drawable folder, then put the custom icon in the folder and use the drawable related path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for me:

I've created a drawable folder: Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable and set the BuildAction of the icon to AndroidResource.

In the AndroidManisfest I was able to get the icon:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/iconnotifi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the drawable folder under Platforms.Android.Resources. I then added a png image called success.png with MauiImage build action. I did not edit or add anything to the AndroidManifest file.

```
notification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.success);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a notification icon, then create a drawable folder—`Platforms/Android/Resources/drawable`—and upload an icon image inside of it.  Then add the code for notifications like below.

```
 private void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        var channelId = $"{PackageName}.general";
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "General", NotificationImportance.Default);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        
//code for notification icon
       FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.SmallIconRef = Resource.Drawable.notificationicon;

        FirebaseCloudMessagingImplementation.ChannelId = channelId;
}
```